# Refresh webpage from IE11 F12 developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Does anyone know the keyboard shortcut for refreshing current webpage in IE11 when focus is set on F12 developer tools? F5 only works when focus is set on the browser itself, so the way I am doing it now is clicking the IE and hitting F5. Combination of keyboard shortcuts would do as well.

I have F12 developer tools pinned.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
Ctrl + R
```

It works for IE11.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make it refresh by pressing `CTRL + R`.